# Split file on pattern matching with different header into files using AWK

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I've a file that needs to be separated based on search pattern into multiple files and different headers for different files. I can split the file but unable to add different header to different files. Here's the code I tried:

```
BEGIN {
    {
       a=substr($0,38,2)

       if(a=="HD")
       {    
        print"a","b","c"...
         OFS="|"  
        }
       if(a=="AS")
        {    
        print"e","f","g"...
        OFS="|"
        }
    }   
}
{
       a=substr($0,38,2)

       if(a=="HD")
       {
        FIELDWIDTHS="10 8 10 9 2 1 1 11 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 8 60 30 30 32 32 27 18 11 346"
        OFS="|"  
        }
        if(a=="AS")
        {       
        FIELDWIDTHS="10 8 10 9 2 1 7 30 14 14 14 14 625"
        OFS="|"
        }
}
{
  $1=$1
  print > a".txt"
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `FIELDWIDTHS` is a gawk extension. I have added the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like the below? And as far as I see, setting `FIELDWITHS` only works properly if it was set in the BEGIN block (or when changing an input file...):

```
awk 'NR=1 { HEADER1 = "whatever" ; HEADER2 = "whatever2" ; 
           print HEADER1 > FIRSTFILE ; 
           print HEADER2 > SECONDFILE ; 
         }
    { a=substr($0,38,2)
      OFS="|"
      print $0 >> a".txt"
    }' INPUTFILE
```